# Tailwind is not working on my vue project

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css

I installed all of steps of Taiwlind but not working. How i fix it.

I just want to install to my project tailwind

Comment: We need more information. Please show us your code or explain what you did.

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons why Tailwind is not working in your project.

- Make sure that you have installed Tailwind using the correct command in your terminal or command prompt, depending on your operating system. You can use the following command to install Tailwind:

> npm install tailwindcss

- Check that you have created a configuration file for Tailwind in your project. You can create a configuration file by running the following command in your
  terminal

> npx tailwindcss init

Ensure that you have included the Tailwind CSS file in your project. You can include the file in your HTML or CSS by adding the following line of code:
scss

```
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```

Check that you have properly configured your build process to compile your CSS code. If you are using a build tool like Webpack or Gulp, you will need to configure it to compile your Tailwind CSS code.